# What is the recommended way to handle multiple api calls from angular to backend server on the same page(=angular component)?

Tags: django, api, backend, restful-url

I'm a backend developing using python/django stack to build a backend api server for our team's frontend developer, who uses angular2 to build SPA for our service.

There are times when frontend need to make GET api call to two or more separate resources to backend server.

For example, we have `payments` page, which needs information both from `users` and `products` tables.

Is it better to make two separate calls at endpoints as follows:

```
/api/users/:user_id
/api/products/:product_id
```

or it better to make backend django server to do some data processing to mix up the information and return the results containing both `user-related info` and `product-related info` at a single endpoint as follows:

```
/api/payments/:payment_id
```

Which  do you think is more standard de facto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See its totally upto you how will you going to handle this.

But according to me, if one call is dependent to another's response than you can mix the response on backend side
else its better to call indvidually on the client side, reason is response will be faster in this case 
because there is no time consumption for calculation etc.

Answer (score 1):

has write an angular backend by Django Rest Framework,my opinion is,for more efficient to use,the second way is better;for faster completion of the backend and more convenient maintenance the backend system,first is better.